# How Subtract 2 values in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to Subtract  2 values and show the result in the index .

The AmountOfRent is AmountOfRent , and the Receipt the user will enter in the Crete , so when back to the index the Balance will show

this is my Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Index(ContractMonth am)
    {

        am.Balance = am.contracts.AmountOfRent - am.Receipt;

        return View(am);
    }
```

This is the view :

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Monthe)
        </th>
     
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Receipt)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Balance)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContractsId)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>


@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Monthe)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contracts.AmountOfRent)
        </td>
   
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Receipt)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Balance)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contracts.Contract_Num)
        </td>
       
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Which thing is stopping you?

Comment: There is error and it is noe come ,, so i think may be is wrong

Comment: When i add the  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))

Comment: because i have Get index , and Post Index

Comment: Parser Error This is the name of error

Comment: Please edit your question and add all information about you want to do. That's not enough to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to subtract two numbers and show there result in view you can do this in razor view by doing this.

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Monthe)
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Receipt)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Balance)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContractsId)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>


@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Monthe)
    </td>
    <td>
        @{ var reuslt=item.contracts.AmountOfRent-item.Receipt;}
        @result
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Receipt)
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.AmountOfRent - item.Receipt
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contracts.Contract_Num)
    </td>

</tr>
}

</table>
```